# Finding the number of subsets with sum equal to k

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Can anyone explain me the dynamic algorithm, that finds number of subsets with sum equal to k.
I searched in Google, but cant find any simple explanation! Sorry for my English!
Here is the code:

```
int numbers[MAX];

int GetmNumberOfSubsets()
    {
        int dp[MAX];
        dp[0] = 1;
        int currentSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            currentSum += numbers[i];
            for (int j = min(sum, currentSum); j >= numbers[i]; j--)
                dp[j] += dp[j - numbers[i]];
        }

        return dp[sum];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DP solution should be 2-dimensional, 1 dimension for the sum, and 1 dimension for the number of elements.

The recursive formula defining this solution is:

```
DP(x,i) = 0    x < 0
DP(0,i) = 1
DP(x,0) = 0    x > 0
DP(x,i) = DP(x-numbers[i],i-1) + DP(x,i-1)
```

And it should be something like:

```
    int dp[MAX+1][sum+1];
    int i, x;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX+1; i++) { 
         dp[i][0] = 1;
    }
    for (x = 1; x < sum+1; x++) { 
         dp[0][x] = 0
    }
    for (i = 1; i < MAX+1; i++) { 
       for (x = 1; x < sum+1; x++) { 
           dp[i][x] = dp[i-1][x];
           if (x >= numbers[i])
             dp[i][x] += dp[i][x-numbers[i]];
        }
     }
    return dp[MAX][sum];
```

(Hope I didn't have minor issues, didn't test it - but it should give you idea how to implement it once recursive formulas are clear)

Comment: @SvendHansen Why? The idea is to nullify solutions that "pass" the desired sum, so every solution that reaches negative value of `x`, will yield 0 solutions.

Comment: What about the test `if (x <= numbers[i])`. Should that not be `>=`? To ensure the index on the line below won't be negative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to find the number of subsets with sum equal to k:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int count = 0,K;
void noofsubsets(int arr[], int sum, int N){
    if(N==0){
        if(sum==K)
            count++;
        return;
    }
    noofsubsets(arr, sum, N-1);
    noofsubsets(arr, sum+arr[N-1], N-1);
}
```

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution using recursion ...
considering two cases
i) Including first element of an array.
ii) without first array element.

```
`

def subSetsSumK(arr, v, k) :

    if (k == 0) :
        for value in v :
            print(value, end=" ")
        print()
        return
    
    if (len(arr)== 0):
        return
    si=0
    v1 = [] + v

    v1.append(arr[si])

    subSetsSumK(arr[1:], v1, k - arr[si])
    subSetsSumK(arr[1:], v, k)
   
def subSetsSumK(arr, k):

    v = []
    subSetsSumK(arr,v, k)


# Driver code

arr = [ 2,1,3,2 ]
k_sum = 4
subSetsSumK(arr,k)
```